# How to solve this formula using recursion in Python?

Tags: python, recursion

I have to use recursion to compute the following formula:

[image]

I am not really sure how to do this. This is what I have so far:

```
def equation(i):
    if i == 0:
        return 15
    else:
        return
```

I am not sure how to make this into a recursive function after the else.

Comment: This seems like a poor example for using recursion because this is a straightforward one-line computation. Are you sure you understand the assignment correctly?

Comment: It's unclear what it means to calculate this kind of expression with recursion.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to compute that recursively, or even iteratively. The natural implementation would be `return 3*i**2 + 2*i + 15`. This suggests we're missing some important context.

Comment: Are you sure you are required to use recursion to solve this? What is the exact question/problem?

Comment: Is your issue simply not understanding how to code something recursively or is it not knowing how to express or solve the equation in a recursive manner?  (I am assuming that this is an assignment meaning I'm willing to help but am none to eager to provide code.)

Comment: I added a picture of the question onto the post

Comment: I am studying for the class final. I already submitted this for a grade, I am just trying to understand it for the final. This isn't a current assignment it has passed

Comment: You're not computing `(3i^2 + 2i + 15)` you're computing the summation of `(3i^2 + 2i + 15)` for all values of `i` from 0 to n

Comment: The formula is *not equivalent* to the one you original posted, you left out the very important summation part. Do you understand what that equation is saying?

Comment: Not entirely sure... I see equation(2)   3(2)^2+2(2)+15

Comment: @Paul If `n = 5` then you have to return `equation(0) + equation(1) + ... + equation(5)`

Answer (score 0):

I think that works:

```
def equation(i):
    if i == 0: return 15
    return (3*i*i + 2*i + 15) + equation(i-1)
```

Comment: That's going to loop forever if you call `equation(-1)`

Comment: Usually summation are interpreted such as `i <= n`, so input shoud always be positive

Comment: @LeonardoChirivì  I would pedanticly argue that a negative input should give a 0 value rather than an error, a bit like a for i in range(3,2):

Comment: Well all it takes is an input check, which i didn't bother